# Why was my "not an answer" flag declined?

Tags: discussion, answers, declined-flags

So I flagged an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28016178/3041194) that I thought was a comment, although my flag was declined quite quickly. So I'm wondering am I wrong in thinking that this is an invalid answer? All the answer said was:

> I would suggest using $_SESSION to store a variable on the client side.

I was thinking that since this is a simple suggestion it should be a comment instead. (*Although I don't believe it is*) Is the above answer a valid one, if so why is it?

Comment: @Rizier123 Yes I have, and although it does not directly meet those cases I have flagged things like this quite a few times and have almost always have been *helpful*.

Comment: @Rizier123: Spam is defined on SE as UCE (Unsolicited Commercial Advertisement).

Answer (score 5):

Compare:

> I would suggest using $_SESSION to store a variable on the client side.

With:

> - Has anyone found a solution for this yet?
> - Thanks for the solution, but I still have a problem...
> - Here is my updated code [should be an edit to the question]
> - I like turtles.

Comment: Then in that case is: *"I would suggest using jQuery"* valid?

Comment: In which group do you place "I would suggest indenting your code for better readability"?

Comment: @AlexK Wat? It contains no information at all, and I wouldn't even call it an appropriate comment. It's VLQ, right?

Comment: @Fundamental Unless the question was about whether or not to indent the code, that would not be an answer, since it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: How far has an answer to go? If an answer suggests to change a few variable names to clear the code up (which is nice and helps understanding the question and may lead the author of the question to look at the right place but shouldn't affect the behaviour of the code itself) and asks for further clarifications is it an answer?

Comment: I don't get your point here, because my last example is clearly different from your four cases but obviously does *not answer the question*. The question was: *"How do I update the input value on demand requesting its value from a php class?"*. To make my point more blunt, in your case *"Use a variable"* is a valid answer.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek "Use a variable" *is* a valid answer. It's not a *good* answer, and it's quite possibly not even a correct or relevant answer, but it is an attempt to answer the question. The Not An Answer flag is reserved only for things which are not remotely an attempt to answer the question, such as the examples listed here. They should be apparent regardless of whether you have any expertise in the tags in use.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Alright, I see now. But link-only answers are attempts, and it's common to flag them as "not-an-answer".

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek As far as I can tell, there's still some disagreement around link-only answers. My preferred interpretation matches [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370), and (short of not flagging at all) is probably the safest in terms of not getting flags declined.