# Is this really an answer?

Tags: support, answers, declined-flags

Yesterday I came across a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28015068/how-to-group-by-date-accounting-for-timezones-and-dst) at first thinking it was a duplicate, but actually was not.

In the course of searching for an existing question that could help the OP of the question, I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748547/mysql-date-sub-date-add-that-accounts-for-dst/7528286#7528286) which has the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7528286/2422013):

[image]

The answer seems to fit the description of `not an answer`:

> This was posted as an answer, but it d**oes not attempt to answer the
>   question.** It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question,
>   or deleted altogether.

This answer asks for clarification rather than providing an actual answer, so I went and flagged it as `not an answer`, *however*...

[image]

...the flag was declined as `a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it`.

Am I incorrect in thinking that the answer *isn't* an answer?
If so, *what* makes this an answer?

I realise that the flag might have been declined due to it being the accepted answer, but Stack Overflow is a reference site and I don't see this answer being of use to future readers.

Breakdown on exactly *why* I don't think this is an answer:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've asked a [question like this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283977/why-was-my-not-an-answer-flag-declined) and from what I understand in the answer is that *any* **attempt** to answer the question counts (even if it doesn't even remotely answer the question). Basically the part that says *"you should try and avoid them when possible"* counts as an answer itself.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek It seems that now this is less of a 'is this an answer' and is rather a 'what is the correct way to handle this?' question. Now it has been explained I can see *why* this qualifies as an answer, but as I mentioned below it is in need of *serious* cleaning-up.

Comment: No, it's a question.

Comment: The first and third sentences are [rhetorical questions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question), a.k.a. statements phrased in the form of a question. The answerer is not asking for clarification. The last sentence doesn't really contribute to the answer, but it doesn't invalidate the rest of the answer.

Comment: @JLRishe Yes I know that, but rhetorical questions in answers do not suit the format of Stack Overflow (or Stack Exchange at that) *at all*.

Comment: @cybermonkey There is *nothing* wrong with having rhetorical questions in an answer on SO.  Nothing about the format prohibits them.

Comment: @Servy The bottom line is that the community seems to be split almost perfectly halfway on this issue, so there doesn't seem to be a right/wrong answer to this (and nobody else has confirmed what you've brought up).

Comment: @cybermonkey You cannot delete the question given that there are multiple answers.

Comment: @Servy True, but there's nothing a good 'ol moderator flag can't solve when it comes to a request to delete my own question.

Comment: @cybermonkey They can certainly disassociate the post from your account.  They're not going to delete a quality post because you say you want it deleted, or because you don't like the answer that you got.

Comment: @Servy So *now* you're saying this is a 'quality post'?

Comment: @cybermonkey Sure it is.  It's an interesting situation to consider; it's a situation that appears, at first glance, to have one resolution, but another when looked at more closely the opposite happens to be the case.  It's a great example to bring up as a result of this confusion.  Why else do you think it's gotten 25 upvotes?  There are plenty of very low quality *comments* here, but the *posts* themselves have plenty of value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NAA is a flag with a [high (or low, as the case may be) bar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/4099598): *any* answer that could be an answer to **some** question on SO, whether or not it's this one, and whether or not it is or was or could be correct, does not qualify for being flagged. It's only answers that are not even wrong that can be flagged this way: new questions, revisions to the question, thanks, requests for clarifications, bumps, irrelevant noise… oh, and [link-only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/274165), which contain no valid answer* if you rot their link.

*Only, at most, a description of an answer that is not actually provided in the post.

Comment: Yes, I know what a NAA flag is what what answers should be flagged with it, that part didn't need explaining. As others here have mentioned, the answer is *only* an answer if one cares to take it out of context as it requires some in-depth reading to actually get what the answer is here, and I'm *still* not actually sure where the answer actually is.

This seems to be more of a case of 'confusing answer' syndrome, but nobody seems to actually understand the answer well enough in order to edit it.

Comment: @cybermonkey: Fair enough. Myself, I know that despite flagging lots of NAA of all types correctly, it's still confusing enough that I could use rehearsal of the definition, so most others probably can too for similar reasons. When I'm somewhat more awake I can try to explain more why this answer's confusing properties are not enough to meet the bar.

Comment: @cybermonkey It's only *not* an answer if you take it out of context.  Taking it *out* of context doesn't turn it *into* an answer.

Answer (score 17):

The real question being asked here is:

> Is there a way I can say to account for DST for a given statement or session?

The author then follows it up with the solution that he found, and explained why that solution didn't work for him.

Functionally, the answer that you quoted is saying that the problem that the OP has with his proposed solution isn't a real problem.  In effect this means that he's saying that the answer to the OP's question is, "use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`".

While taken out of context, and not actually looking at the question, this isn't clear.  When actually looking at the question this answer is very clearly an answer to the question.  While adding some more explicit statement to the answer along the lines of, "you should just use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`" would make it look more like an answer out of context, it's not actually adding anything of value when looked at in context; I'd consider such a statement to be noise, and wouldn't want to add it.

Reviewing answers entirely out of context has its (rare) dangers.  Thankfully this mod got it right.

Comment: True, but then the answer should be edited or deleted entirely and a new one posted with the correct solution. The answer doesn't directly reference `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` and it's not useful to future readers (such as myself) as they have to analyse it (like you did). *Users shouldn't have to solve puzzles to get the right answer.*

Comment: @cybermonkey If you plan on reading that answer without even reading the question, sure.  That's not the design of the system though.  Future readers can be expected to read through the question before expecting the answers to be meaningful, and so such an edit would be pretty much just noise.  It doesn't reference `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` explicitly, but it does do so *implicitly*.

Comment: I did read the question, and yet the answer doesn't help those who can't use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` for any reason. Apparently the community agrees because since I posted this question, the answer's received two more downvotes.

Comment: @cybermonkey The question doens't say, "I cannot possibly use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP ` under any circumstances.  It says, `Is there a way I can say to account for DST for a given statement or session?`, followed up with a proposed option and some potential concerns.  The answer alleviates those concerns.  If someone else has different problems with that solution they can post a question about how to resolve the problem under a different set of circumstances, or with different constraints.

Comment: @cybermonkey If people feel that the answer isn't useful, isn't correct, or is for whatever reason unhelpful, they can downvote it.  I have no idea if the answer is the best solution to that problem, and so have no intention of voting.  I'm merely saying that it is clearly *an* answer and shouldn't be deleted as NAA.  Voting is there to indicate the quality of that answer.

Comment: True, but then again, this question is the second result on a Google result if I [search for `DATE_SUB/DATE_ADD that accounts for DATE without TIMESTAMP`](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=DATE_SUB/DATE_ADD+that+accounts+for+DATE+without+TIMESTAMP&spell=1); anyone arriving at this question from a search like that would be pretty disappointed and probably go elsewhere.

Comment: @cybermonkey It's impossible to always prevent questions of related but slightly different topics from being returned for any given search.  The fact that you can come up with a search query that results in a question being returned does not mean that the answers is obligated to answer that entirely separate search query.  The answer answers the question asked.  It is clearly not an answer, and should not be deleted on that basis.

Comment: The bottom line is that this answer is phrased in a way that does not make it an answer. If the answer was, say, edited, then it could probably become a *very* good answer with the right amount of editing. *No, I'm not going to edit it myself as it'll likely get rejected as it'll change too much (in the eyes of a reviewer.*

Comment: The answer is phrased in such a way that you thought it wasn't an answer when looking at it out of context, even though it really does answer the question when looked at more closely, and when taken in the context of the question its answering.  While an argument could be made for editing it to remove that potential confusion, there is certainly no basis for deleting the answer just because some people mistakenly thought it wasn't answering the question even though it was.

Comment: *No*, the 'answer' doesn't look like an answer when you first view it. Some digging into the context can 'reveal' the actual answer. My point is that on Stack Overflow answers must be high-quality, and this answer isn't.

Comment: @cybermonkey That's exactly my point.  You *mistakenly* thought that the post isn't an answer, even though it is.  If you feel the post is of low quality, you can use your vote to reflect that.  You flagged it as NAA, and a mod *correctly* declined the flag because the post *is* an answer, and *does* answer the question.  NAA is not for answers that you don't think are of sufficient quality.  It's for answers that aren't answers.

Comment: See my edit. 3/4 of the answer seems to be about future-proofing, maybe the OP of that question *wants* to use whatever they're developing in 33+ years. The real-world answer is that *probably not*, but we can't assume this as it's not useful to future readers.

Comment: My 2 cents: If I were having DST SQL issues and ran into that question and answer, I'd have no idea that was supposed to be a suggestion to use UNIX_TIMESTAMP, nor why. Seems like that would only be obvious to someone who already knew enough to answer the question themselves. As such, I'd much prefer a complete answer in comprehensible English, rather than one that relies on already understanding the context.

Comment: @Dronz I get the same result if I leave the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` out of the search, so your first point's invalid. However I completely agree to your second point as *only* those with good English have been able to interpret the answer properly so far.

Comment: @cybermonkey And if you feel that the answer isn't helpful, you can use your vote to reflect it.  You thinking that the answer isn't useful doesn't make it NAA.  It makes it something you can downvote.

Comment: @Dronz See my previous comments.  If you read the answer in isolation, it can be confusing what it's really suggesting.  When you read the question *and* the answer, it's pretty clear what the answer is proposing.  If you think that it's not clear enough, you're more than welcome to use your vote to reflect that.  None of that is grounds for deleting it as NAA.

Comment: @Servy Please read what I'm saying, I never said the answer isn't helpful, because it does contain some helpful information (see my screenshots in my question). Even when pairing the answer up with the question I *still* can't exactly understand where the answer is in there.

Comment: @cybermonkey The question is saying, "I can't use X to solve by problem because Y".  This post is saying, "Y isn't actually a problem for you," which is implicitly stating, "so you can feel free to use X."  Re-stating the solution in the answer is just going to be redundant for anyone who actually read the question.  If you think that makes the answer low quality, because it's "too subtle" for you, I have no problem with that.  Demanding it be deleted is another matter entirely.

Comment: @Servy I never demanded the answer be deleted. I'm speaking on behalf of all the members who do not posses the English skills to be able to pick apart this answer, non native speakers will find it hard to pick-apart the answer. Even I found it hard, and English is my first language (not native though, so perhaps some friction there).

Comment: @cybermonkey When you flagged it as NAA, you were asking for it to be deleted.  That's what happens to posts that are actually NAA.  By coming here to say that your flag was wrongfully deleted, you're saying the post should have been deleted, but wasn't.  For like the 5th time, if you think the post is unclear, or for whatever reason unhelpful, the appropriate way to convey that is through voting.  If you want to comment, you can do that too.  The flags rejection was 100% correct as this post *is* an answer.

Comment: @Servy Please read the comments on the accepted answer for this question, as it's apparent that this question now isn't about *whether* this is an answer, but *how* poorly-worded answers like this should be handled.

Comment: @cybermonkey And I've told you 6 times now.  If you think an answer is a low quality answer, you can downvote it; you can also comment if you would like to.  What about that don't you understand?

Comment: *sigh*. Read my last comment.

Comment: @cybermonkey Sigh. Read my last 10 comments.  If you want to know how to handle a poor quality answer, I've told you.  You say that you know that the post is an answer, and thus shouldn't be flagged as NAA, you know it should be downvoted if you think it's unclear, and that you can comment if you want.  I cannot possibly comprehend what you don't understand.

Comment: Just to be clear, I woudn't delete it or mark it as not an answer (because it has ideas that could be useful and is trying to answer), but I think cybermonkey's original suggested edit was a very good idea, because it would explicitly and more clearly state what the answer is for those of use who otherwise struggle to see the answer due to language or not knowing the context so well.

Comment: @Dronz Well said, and as Servy seems to know what they're doing I nominate them to do the edit.

Comment: No more comments? Dang it, I was having fun - it was like watching a good tennis match.